# Is there any way to use AddComponent with a script in Unity if there is no instance of that script in the game yet?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, components, unityscript

I need a way to add a script to an object that I just Instantiated. Ideally I could just set the script to add in the inspector. The problem is that I can't use

```
public Component scriptToAdd;
```

because then I would need to already have an empty object or something with the script on it. While that would work it feels kind of dirty or hackish to make an empty that just stores references to something. Also the point of doing it like this for me is to make it more efficient to swap out different scripts. If I had to swap out a script on an empty and then drag the new one in I'd lose on some of that efficiency I'm after. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

After you instantiate, you should use the GameObject.AddComponent() Class, to add any component Type you want.

for example, if you want to add a camera to the scene.

```
void Start () {

        GameObject myNewCamera = new GameObject();
            //creates an empty game object, you can already attach components to it.
        myNewCamera.AddComponent<Camera>();
            //adds a component of type Camera
}
```

You can also use the overloaded constructor

```
GameObject myNewCamera = new GameObject("my object name", typeof(ScriptToAdd));
GameObject myNewCamera = new GameObject("my object name", typeof(ScriptToAdd), typeof(MoreComponentsToAdd));
```

Also, you should never be afraid of using an empty GameObject on your scene, for keeping information, references, variable values, saves, or anything really. It doesn't really affect the performance of your game, and you can make your life easy just by having an easy to find tag, such as "Engine".
Then you can access anything just by adding:

```
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Engine");
```

I hope I was able to help you :)

-Noe

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late, but I'm not sure this answers my question. I want to add a script that I don't know the name of. This is why i need a variable to hold the name of the target script. Maybe that clears things up?